# Sublime is failed to recognize multiple quotes

Tags: scala, sublimetext3

How can I make sublime to recognize Scala triple quotes with an extra double quote in the string?

[image: sublime text]

Comment: Maybe try `"""\"` or `\""""` ... it might need to be escaped.

Comment: @I'L'l It doesn't work.

Comment: Try using single quotes around it perhaps... `'"""` instead of four double quotes.

Comment: If you are open to workarounds you could do s""" "some string" """.trim

Comment: What build are you using? It [looks fine](http://i.stack.imgur.com/3qfHf.png) in Build 3095 (I'm using the [Neon Color Scheme](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/Neon%20Color%20Scheme))...